# Printing truth table in "1" and "0" using boolean variables

Tags: java

i am new to programming. i am trying to printing out a truth table. It contains AND, OR, XOR, NOT. i completed first 3 parts. but when i am trying to code that "NOT" part i am getting a error "bad operand for int unary operator (!)" from the compiler.

```
class oneandzero{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        boolean p,q;
        int a,b;
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT P\tNOT Q");
        p=false; q=false;
        a=(p)?1:0;
        b=(q)?1:0;
        System.out.println(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+(a&b)+"\t"+(a|b)+"\t"+(a^b)+"\t"+(!a)+"\t"+(!b));
        p=false; q=true;
        a=(p)?1:0;
        b=(q)?1:0;
        System.out.println(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+(a&b)+"\t"+(a|b)+"\t"+(a^b)+"\t"+(!a)+"\t"+(!b));
        p=true; q=false;
        a=(p)?1:0;
        b=(q)?1:0;
        System.out.println(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+(a&b)+"\t"+(a|b)+"\t"+(a^b)+"\t"+(!a)+"\t"+(!b));
        p=true; q=true;
        a=(p)?1:0;
        b=(q)?1:0;
        System.out.println(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+(a&b)+"\t"+(a|b)+"\t"+(a^b)+"\t"+(!a)+"\t"+(!b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you can only use NOT operator when you are checking something[greater/less/equa/condidtionsl anyting like that] . You just cant use NOT operator before int.

Answer (score 2):

The logical NOT operator `!` only acts on boolean values:

```
!true == false
!false == true
```

You probably want the bitwise NOT operator `~`, which acts on integers:

```
~0b00000000 == 0b11111111
~0b11111111 == 0b00000000

// or for single bits, (~x & 1):
~0 & 1 == 1
~1 & 1 == 0
```

Comment: ~0==1 is wrong because 0000 0000 is the 8 bit value of 0. so 2s complement of 0 is -1. i mean  ~0==-1 and -1==-2

Comment: @JayarajRohan You're absolutely correct, I was thinking about single bits but didn't make that clear. I've updated my answer to reflect this a bit better.

Comment: Thank you for your help.